# database gravando só a senha

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Esse é meu primeiro post aqui, já acompanho o forum a um bom tempo mas nunca tive vontade de interagir, hoje surgiu essa vontade junto com um probleminha ...

To aprendendo `html, css, php` e etc... a partir de tutoriais, após inúmeros fracassos eu acabo conseguindo realizar o que pretendo. Tenho o costume de assistir vários tutoriais sobre o mesmo tempo e após assistir todos decido qual usar, baseado na divergência de informações entre eles e na minha intuição. Até que dá certo, mas sempre acontece algo de errado e aí eu começo a procurar conteúdo para resolver. Um dos problemas que me persegue é que eu não sei como citar o erro acontecido, tipo este que está acontecendo agora. Então creio que aqui seria a melhor opção.

**O problema:**
`

```
<?php </br>
session_start();</br>
$_SESSION['message']  = '';

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','accounts'); </br>

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { <br>
    if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']){ <br>
        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']); <br>
        $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']); <br>
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) "
        . "VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        //if the query
        if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "deu certo";
            header("location: welcome.php");
        }

        else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Usuario nao pode ser add";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

*Dificuldade entender essa tag do codigo, meu deus.*

[image: mysql workbench]

Essa é a tabela que eu criei:
mas quando eu vou checar o db só tem isso:
[image: phpmyadmin]

Essa é minha primeira pergunta, se fiz algo de errado por favor, me digam. Obrigado!

Comment: Poste o formulário que trás os valores, pois isso é problema nele, e não no insert. Imprima na tela a variável `$sql`, veja se realmente estão vindo os valores para ela. Precisa ir fazendo testes para ver onde está o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é no formulário que trás os dados via `POST`.

Você não colocou a tag `name="username"` no seu input:

Atual:

`<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>`

Correto:

`<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required autofocus>`

`<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Valid Email" name="email" required autocomplete>`

Além disso:

Seu campo `password` só está com `10 caracteres`.

O tipo `md5` gera `32 caracteres`.

Aumente o campo no seu banco.

Mais sobre MD5: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: Poste o formulário para ver como está vindo seu `POST`

Comment: Edite sua resposta, poste todo conteúdo do seu form.

Comment: Por aqui deu caracteres excedidos, publiquei no CodePen codepen.io/Rytter/pen/bYRzGE –

Comment: Seus inputs estão faltando... vou editar minha resposta

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, deu super certo. Não sei nem como agradecer a você.

Comment: Opa ! tranquilo. Mas sempre que for postar, edite e pergunta e poste tudo nela. Assim ajuda um próximo.

Answer (score -1):

Vamos lá, primeiro tire esses `<br/>` de dentro do PHP, se quer utiliza-los coloque num `echo`. Para evitar problemas com aspas etc no seu `SQL` utilize {}:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$email}', '{$password}')";
```

Se quer saber se os dados realmente estão chegando de um:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

Assim você verá o Array() POST inteiro, só assim conseguirá entender de onde vem o problema, se é no POST ou não.

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela atenção.